# Apache rewrite rule help, strange results

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, s3-rewrite-rules

I am going in circle on this.

```
RewriteRule ^Homes-by-price Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=999999999 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Homes-by-price/([0-9]+) Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=$1 [NC,L]
```

The first line works. When I enter /Homes-by-price and get the page showing

```
 Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=999999999
```

But when I type in

```
 /Homes-by-price/100000
```

I should get

```
 Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=100000
```

Instead I get a blank web page and the debug console showing me the HTML script for the page.

If I type in

```
 /Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=100000
```

everything displays correctly.

Complete htaccess (The commented out portions where removed for trouble shooting this issue.)

```
DirectoryIndex default.html

#Block listing of folder contents
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine on

#Rewrite rule for force https and www
# located in 000-default.conf


#rewrite rules single listing page (real-estate-listing.php)
#RewriteRule ^home-for-sale/mls/([0-9]+) real-estate-listing.php?mls=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^home-for-sale/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) real-estate-listing.php?city=$1&address=$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^commercial-property-for-sale/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) real-estate-listing.php?city=$1&address=$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^land-for-sale/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) real-estate-listing.php?city=$1&address=$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^business-for-sale/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) real-estate-listing.php?city=$1&address=$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^property-for-sale/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) real-estate-listing.php?city=$1&address=$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^investment-property-for-sale/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) real-estate-listing.php?city=$1&address=$2 [NC,L]

#rewrite rules for search page showing multiple listings (Real-Estate-Listings.php)
RewriteRule ^Homes-by-price/([0-9]+) Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Homes-by-price Real-Estate-Listings.php?maxPrice=999999999 [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html|php|json)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I suspect it is because you didn't escape the dash. Try ^Homes\-by\-price

Comment: Just tried that, it didn't work. Same result. - Thanks anyway.

Comment: I also did a syntax check for the entire htaccess script. Everything checks out.

Comment: @NealM After changing the htaccess did you clear your cache? Changes may not be taking effect, it's had some really weird affects for me where it seemingly cached _part_ of the htaccess but not all of it

Comment: In the DevTools I have "Disable cache" check. Plus I am using Ctrl+refresh to reload the page. On your suggestion, I went into Chromes setting and manually cleared the cache and browsing history. Finally I tried the URL in Edge. Nothing worked. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Both rules should go to same target with first target :

```
RewriteRule ^Homes-by-price Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=999999999 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Homes-by-price/([0-9]+) Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=$1 [NC,L]
```

Every request starts with `Homes-by-price` will be handled by the first rule so the second rule is useless, just put the last rule in the beginning like this :

```
RewriteRule ^Homes-by-price/([0-9]+) Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Homes-by-price Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=999999999 [NC,L]
```

Test it like this and let me know

Comment: Nope, That didn't do it either. Still the exact same thing.

Comment: paste ur htaccess

Comment: Just did in original post.

Comment: @NeaM please clear browser cache the test it is work fine for me

Comment: Cleared the cache and change the URL to  
    /Homes-by-price/100011
if didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it did resolve the issue.

By use the full URL in the rewrite statement it now works. It now reads:

```
RewriteRule ^Homes-by-price/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) https://example.com/Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=$1&maxPrice=$2 [DPI,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by your first rule. If you remove the first rule, the second rule runs normally. Your second rule is never actually getting run, this is because the first rule still matches the URL. So it makes the change to `Real-Estate-Listings.php?minPrice=0&maxPrice=999999999` and then adds `/100000` on to the end. Which is causing the error.

Removing the `[L]` from the first rule *should* fix this. Since the first rule is still matching the URL it runs and then the `[L]` flag stops any further rules from being run past it.

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In
>   most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules
>   will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or
>   the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current
>   rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

For more information on how the RewriteRule Flags work, you read the documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html